# How to execute a php script on ssh server through a capistrano 2 deploy ruby script

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, capistrano

I need to execute a php script on the deployment server from capistrano 2 deploy script and need to get the output in a variable. I am trying following command which is used to execute shell in ruby

```
result =%x[php -q #{myDeployPath}/myfile.php]
```

I am getting "Could not open file" error , this is because it is trying run this php on my local server from where I am deploying on the required server.I am able to execute normal "run" command on the deployment server but have no idea getting output in a variable "result".

I am able to execute this php on serevr by following command but not able to capture the output in the script back.

```
 run "php -q #{myDeployPath}/myfile.php"
```

Please help.. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
result =%x[ssh username@remote.server php -q #{myDeployPath}/myfile.php]
```

Some information about setting up SSH to make this possible (I posted this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112087/broadcast-or-send-machine-readable-code-to-ssh-clients/112093#112093 )

#### Step #1

First make sure the client box (running that Ruby) has a SSH private key set up on it: `ssh-keygen`.

#### Step #2

Then make sure the public key for said private key is on the remote computer.  You need to put it at the end of a file with a name like this:

```
 /home/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

${user} is the username on the more powerful computer.

Also, make sure on the powerful computer, `/home/${user}/.ssh/` has the permissions 700 (`drwx------`), and `/home/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys` has permissions 600 (`-rw-------`). Use `chmod` to set permissions:

```
$ chmod 700 /home/${user}/.ssh/
$ chmod 600 /home/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Capistrano script executes all other commands without requiring ssh again , do I need ssh again for executing a php and getting its result